# mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'"); to solve '???' character

Tags: php, utf-8, character

I have been trying to insert "**mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");**" into the set of code shown below as the characters display on the webpage seems to be ?????? instead of the Chinese character. However, I am not sure which part of the code should I place it at and am unsure if "**mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");**" is the exact code to be put in. Please help, thanks in advance.

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli ("XXXX", "XXXX", 'XXXX', "XXXX");    

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT cater_id, cater_name, cater_name_cn, cater_description, cater_description_cn, cater_img, cater_price, cater_appetizer, cater_appetizer_cn, cater_savory, cater_savory_cn, cater_beverage, cater_beverage_cn, cater_dessert, cater_dessert_cn FROM catering")) {

    $result = $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($cater_id, $cater_name, $cater_name_cn, $cater_description, $cater_description_cn, $cater_img, $cater_price, $cater_appetizer, $cater_appetizer_cn, $cater_savory, $cater_savory_cn, $cater_beverage, $cater_beverage_cn, $cater_dessert, $cater_dessert_cn);}
```

Comment: *"`mysql_query(“SET NAMES 'UTF8'”);` to solve '???'"* - Look at this and think for 2 mins. This isn't *gin & tonic* ;)

Comment: is your html page set to use the meta utf8 charset, is your html/php page saved with the utf8 encoding?

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry, don't quite get what you mean.

Comment: `mysql_query` - `mysqli` - what's missing? and what's different between the two? I want "you" to solve it, that way you won't do the same mistake again ;)

Comment: @PatrickEvans no, it is not set to use meta utf8 charset.

Comment: So, figured it out yet? If not, I'll tell you. It's all about "learning" here. After all, it's Sunday.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried the code below but there seem to have an error.

$mysqli = new mysqli ("XXXX", "XXXX", 'XXXX', "XXXX");
mysqli("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
//2: Prepare the statement


if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT cater_id, cater_name, cater_name_cn, cater_description, cater_description_cn, cater_img, cater_price, cater_appetizer, cater_appetizer_cn, cater_savory, cater_savory_cn, cater_beverage, cater_beverage_cn, cater_dessert, cater_dessert_cn FROM catering")) { .......

Comment: You've tried `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");` but you see, `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions do **not** mix together. Try  `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");` instead just before your query.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I will call you my life saver ('; Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question closer as per my comment:

You've tried `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");`

But you see, `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions do **not** mix together.

Try/use  `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");` instead just before your query.